# How to save file in phone internal memory?

Tags: android, cordova

Hi I am making an android application suing phonegap.Here I have to save pdf document in phone internal memory.But it is saving in phone SD card.
Please help me to save pdf File in phone Internal memory my code is

```
   var filename = "read-write.txt";
         var filePath = "file:///sdcard/read-write.txt";

function saveFile(){
           window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccessSave,onErrorSave);     
       }
       function onSuccessSave(fileSystem){
           var sdcardEntry = fileSystem.root;
           sdcardEntry.getFile(filename,{create: true}, gotFileEntry, failEntry);
       }
       function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
           fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, failWrite);
       }
       function gotFileWriter(fileWriter){
           fileWriter.onwrite = function (evt) {
               alert("Write was successful!");
               document.getElementById("textarea").value = "";
           };
           fileWriter.write(document.getElementById("textarea").value);
       }
       function failWrite(error){
           alert("Failed to get a file writer for " + filename); 
       }
       function failEntry(error){
           alert("Got error while reading " + filename + " " + error);
       }
       function onErrorSave(error){
           alert("Got Error while gaining access to file system");
       }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- Avoid using file://sdcard/ Use **String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();** instead
- In my phone, the tip above works even if there is no SD Card, but if you want to try another alternative, try using *String path = Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath();*
- Remember to change de Android Manifest:

> `<uses-permission
>   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: which change is needed in Android Manifest?I have same problem

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> `

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own plugin for PhoneGap and have direct control of the native side methods for saving files.

First develop the javascript plugin:

```
var FileSaver = {   
};

FileSaver.saveFile = function(successCallback, errorCallback, fileName) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "FileSaverPlugin", "saveFile", [fileNameToSave, filePathOfPdf]);
};
```

Next, add a class called FileSaverPlugin.java:

```
public class FileSaverPlugin extends CordovaPlugin
{
    private CallbackContext callbackContext = null;

    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException 
    {
            this.callbackContext = callbackContext;

            if (action.equals("saveFile")) 
            {
                this.saveFile(args.getString(0), args.getString(1));
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
    }

    public void saveFile(String fileNameToSave, String filePathOfPdf)
    {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        File file = new File(filePathOfPdf);
        byte[] byteArray = this.readFileToByteArray(file);

        try 
        {
            // Saves the pdf to the internal phone memory.
            outputStream = cordova.getActivity().openFileOutput(fileNameToSave, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(byteArray);
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private byte[] readFileToByteArray(File file)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try 
        {
            BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            buffer.read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            buffer.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

So, when you need to save a file simply use this JavaScript method:

```
FileSaver.saveFile("name-of-file-save-in-internal-memory.pdf", "/path/to/pdf/aDocument.pdf");
```

**NOTE**: Be sure to add the plugin to the `config.xml` file of PhoneGap. Also, this is using PhoneGap 2.8, for older versions refer to the [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).